# Error using ACL in Appcelerator ACS

Tags: javascript, mobile, appcelerator, acl

I am trying to use the ACL functionality to control what posts a user can share with others. When I associate an ACL (through the ACS Management console using a browser) to a post, than I get the following error:
"[ERROR][TiJSError(  629)] (main) [1,124536] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined"

Basically, the code only works for Post content and title if there is an ACL attached. However, if I remove the ACL, the entire code works fine. Am I missing something? Here is how my code looks...

```
       app.Cloud.Posts.query(function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
            if (e.posts.length == 0) {
                //alert("There is no information to display. Please enter some data and try again.");

                table.setData([
                    { title: 'No Results!' }
                ]);
            }
            else {
                var data = [];
                for (var i = 0, l = e.posts.length; i < l; i++) {
                    data.push(Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                        id: e.posts[i].id,
                        title: e.posts[i].title,
                        content: e.posts[i].content,
                        username: e.posts[i].user.username,
                        userfirst_name: e.posts[i].user.first_name,
                        userlast_name: e.posts[i].user.last_name,
                        useremail: e.posts[i].user.email,
                        type: e.posts[i].custom_fields.type,
                        coordinates: e.posts[i].custom_fields.coordinates,
                        latitude : e.posts[i].custom_fields.coordinates[0][1],
                        longitude : e.posts[i].custom_fields.coordinates[0][0]                          
                    }));
                }
                table.setData(data);
            }
        }
        else {
            error(e);
        }
    });
```

Any pointers on how to fix this will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you debugged and looked at each "posts" object in the response array?  When using ACL's it will usually still return an object with an id for a disallowed post. for example:

```
{"posts":[{"id":"534dfgdfg44"},{"id":"5436rgdf345f3f3", "username":"meow", etc....}]}
```

Therefore you need to validate that each object in the returned array has the data you are looking for.

Hope this helps.